# IBM HTTP - RewriteRule for http://hostname:port/abc/def/ghi

Tags: apache, httpserver

I'm a newb. I want a rewrite rule that translates URLs on the form:

http://hostname:port/abc/**def**/ghi
to

http://hostname:port/abc/**XYZ**/ghi

abc is a fixed prefix. ghi is the query string which is back referenced.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe :

```
RewriteRule ^/abc/def(.*) /abc/XYZ$1 [QSA]
```

Hope it helps